# Submitting a form with an INPUT outside it, and after modiying a value

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a `form`, with a couple of `<input>` tags inside. I have a submit button (actually an `<input>` of type `BUTTON`, *not* `SUBMIT`) that is **outside** the form. I have the form set up similar to this —

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" action="test.jsp" onsubmit="return modify_value();" method="POST">
<input name="test1" id="test1" type="TEXT" value="A"/>
<input name="test2" id="test2" type="TEXT" value="B"/>
<input name="test3" id="test3" type="HIDDEN"/>
</form>
```

The submit button, which is outside the form, is defined this way —

```
<input type="BUTTON" id="_submit" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"/>
```

And the `modify_value()` JavaScript method looks like this —

```
function modify_value()
{
    var hidden_field = document.getElementById('test3');
    hidden_field.value = 'new_test_value_set_on_clicking';
    return true;
}
```

When the submit button is clicked, I am trying to modify the value of the `test3` element before the form gets submitted. For some reason, I can never read the new value in my servlet.

**Alternate Method - (<del>Doesn't Work Either</del>) WORKS!**

I have tried submitting the form in a slightly different way as well - by setting the button's `onclick` event to point to the `modify_value()` method and in the last line of that method, calling `form.submit()` instead of returning a value (EDIT: And of course, removing the `onsubmit` attribute in the form). This doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did u try removing the onsubmit event in form tag first  and calling the modify_value() on button's onlick as u have mentioned above.. i think that should work.

Comment: @bipen: Oh yes, I did that. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
<input type="BUTTON" id="_submit" onclick="modify_value()"/>
function modify_value()
{
    var hidden_field = document.getElementById('test3');
    hidden_field.value = 'new_test_value_set_on_clicking';
    document.getElementById("testform").Submit();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't work. I've also discussed this in the question, towards the end.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `.submit()` in JavaScript.  The form's `onsubmit` event handler is not called.

I would put the button inside the form, and make it a submit button.  Otherwise it's just a dead button (semantically, and when JavaScript is not available).

<del>In HTML validation you're not allowed an INPUT element outside of a FORM element anyway.</del>  Weird, it seems you are!  Ha ha I never knew that...

---

If you need to work within the restrictions specified within your answer, then remove the onsubmit attribute:

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" action="test.jsp" method="POST">
<input name="test1" id="test1" type="TEXT" value="A"/>
<input name="test2" id="test2" type="TEXT" value="B"/>
<input name="test3" id="test3" type="HIDDEN"/>
</form>
```

...and change the onclick attribute to modify the value...

```
<input type="BUTTON" id="_submit" onclick="modify_value()"/>
```

...and add the form submission to the end of the function, no need to return any value...

```
function modify_value()
{
    var hidden_field = document.getElementById('test3');
    hidden_field.value = 'new_test_value_set_on_clicking';
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. But then my second method doesn't work either. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @GPX: Another way other than putting the button inside the form, and using a real submit button?

Comment: @GPX: I think you might have a different issue, because I can get it to work no problem.  I'll add an edit to my answer.

Comment: Just updated my question, and also marked @polin's answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually now do this entirely in HTML, see the [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input) attribute for <s>submit buttons</s> all `<input>` elements — new with HTML5.

> The form element that the input element is associated with (its *form owner*). The
>   value of the attribute must be an **id** of a `<form>` element in the same
>   document. If this attribute is not specified, this `<input>` element
>   must be a descendant of a `<form>` element. This attribute enables you
>   to place `<input>` elements anywhere within a document, not just as
>   descendants of their form elements.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
<input type="submit" form="download" value="Download Selection" />
```

This button can then be placed anywhere on your page.

Obviously this only works on a limited number of browsers at the moment, but I figured it's worth a mention.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of this. However, we have to take older browsers like IE8 into consideration as well. So this won't be the best solution for me.

Comment: @GPX Heh, I had the same issue to. Such nice things to play with, but then you have to support IE.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

HTML

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" action="test.jsp" onsubmit="return false;" method="POST">  // onsubmit to return false
.....
<input type="submit" id="_submit" onclick="modify_value()"/> //call javascript function
</form>
```

JAVACRIPT

```
function modify_value()
{
   var hidden_field = document.getElementById('test3');
   hidden_field.value = 'new_test_value_set_on_clicking'; // do the things here
   document.getElementById('testform').Submit(); // submit the form
}
```

Comment: ok edited.. please check now.. changed the input type button to submit, and please keep this input inside the form

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't move the `input` tag inside the form nor change its type to `button`. I'm forced to work with such restrictions.

Comment: ok this is getting interesting... did u try alert or log inside modify_value() function , check if it is calling that function or not..... i prefer @polin answer and it should work...

Comment: Oh yes, an alert works! Somehow though, the newly set value isn't actually sent as a part of the form.

Comment: I think I forgot to change a small thing or so. It works now.