# add elements to form from outside form tags on submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a dropdown menu for sort by price: low to high etc

This menu is outside my closing form tag.

How can I add the select option to the form on submit?

So far I have:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#sort_by').change(function(){
 $("#search_form").submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

So the above will submit the form on change but wont add the value of the select option.  How can I add the select option to the form on submit?

Select Menu:

```
<select name="sort_by" id="sort_by">
<option value="Low to High">Low to High</option>
<option value="High to Low">High to Low</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why not remove the form altogether and simply submit via ajax?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930502/submitting-a-form-with-an-input-outside-it-and-after-modiying-a-value

Comment: @SexyTurnip similar question but the answer is in vanilla javascript. OP has requested jQuery, and they haven't asked for the form to submit on change of the select.

Comment: That's why I didn't vote to close. However the concept is identical despite using a framework or not, hence the shared link.

Comment: What is wrong with including the dropdown in the `<form>` set

Comment: @Popnoodles Vanilla JS is jQuery without the wrapper and you use it all the tie when dealing with jQuery too. Where does that vanilla JS fear come from?

Comment: @feela that's not relevant. Would you give someone a PHP answer in C++ just because hiphop compiles php to C++?

Comment: That is a terrible analogy. jQuery _is_ javascript. PHP _is not_ C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is to add an hidden input field inside the form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sort_by" id="myInput">

$('#sort_by').change(function(){
    $('#myInput').val($(this).val());
    $("#search_form").submit();
});
```

remember to remove the name property from the select

if you re using the ajax function you can also build a FormData object and append all your data to it (docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects )

Comment: OP didn't ask for the form to be submitted on change of the select, they asked for the field to be added to the form on submit of the form.

Comment: @Popnoodles Well if you look it already is being submitted on select of dropdown. He has not changed that

Comment: @Vanojx1 Ah yes I see that. The text in the question says otherwise, so it needs clarification from OP.

Comment: this is good as it does not affect the select boxes whilst submitting the form

Answer (score 3):

You want the field to be part of the form on submit, so append the select to the form on submit of the form.

Added clone and hide to avoid a visual change.

```
$('#search_form').on('submit', function(){
    $('#sort_by').clone().hide().appendTo(this);
});
```

Since you're posting the whole page (not ajax), it won't matter that you clone the select with the same ID and don't remove a duplicate clone beforehand.

EDIT

While the text in the question says that you want the select added to the form on submit, the code given says you want the form submitted on change:

```
$('#sort_by').on('change', function(){
    $('#search_form').append($(this).clone().hide()).trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: also visually it would be better to `hide` the appended field `$('#sort_by').appendTo(this).hide()`

Comment: Could be worth hiding.

Comment: this works well, only problem is when I choose an option from the select menu, the select box disappears whilst appending to form, then comes back when I see the results

Comment: In that case use `.clone()`. Updated the answer.

Comment: @user3312792 this is a far tidier solution which doesn't require you to add unneccessary HTML, and should (for the benefit of others too) be the accepted answer.